# Magento 2: Admin Order Date filter showing wrong result

Tags: orders, filter, magento2.2.4, date

I have been trying to filter admin order based on a date but getting the wrong result.

> I have try to filter Purchase Date **from:** 03-03-2019 and **to:** 03-03-2019
>
> **Expected result:** Filter result list should be show Purchase Date **from:** 03-03-2019 and **to:** 03-03-2019

**Actual result:** Filter result list showing Purchase **Date** Mar 4, 2019

I am using Magento ver. 2.2.4

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally debugging i have find the solution. It has been cause of mirasvit report extension conflict with the order date filter.

I have disable Mirasvit_Report extension and then order date filter working fine.